# WPF Callout Anchor start position

Tags: wpf, callout

I have implement Callout control of Blend. Problem which I am facing is anchor point of the Callout starts with some margin from the top, While I want to have anchor from the top left of the callout.
Any help will be appreciated.

What I have now:

[image]
What I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: could you post some xaml , i wasn't able to figure out how to use this class .

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be mistaken about using this control. From MSDN, the [`Callout.AnchorPoint` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.controls.callout.anchorpoint%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) *Gets or sets the position of the callout relative to the top and left corner*. It is used for positioning the control and does *not* alter the shape of the `Callout`.

---

UPDATE >>>

Dude!!! That's a really simple shape... just draw your own one with a `Path`... then you can make it any shape you want:

[image]

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Rect="0,0,300,200">
                    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="30" />
                    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,30">
                        <LineSegment Point="50,10" />
                        <LineSegment Point="50,50" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="0.4" Direction="-135"
            ShadowDepth="10" />
    </Path.Effect>
</Path>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I understand that Acnhor point is for relative position for top left corner. But if I want to change to start location of Anchor is this possible using some style. Or if you can suggest some other control which can resolve this.